# Reading BLOBS: Media Link Entry in OData

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

For reading BLOBS in a OData Service, I am using the DataServiceContext.GetReadStream()
The GetReadStream method synchronously requests a data stream that contains the binary property of the requested entity.

In the AtomPub protocol, the entity is a Media Link Entry and the binary property is the associated Media Resource.

In the code I am using the proxy generated using Datasvcutil.exe. The proxy generates many classes for the entities. Is there any property to detect whether the given entity has binary stream or not.

Currently I call `dataSvcContext.GetReadStream(customer)` and getting ArgumentException for an entity that does not have Media Link property or binary property.

Is there any method available to detect whether entity has binary property or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can check whether your entity contains the following attribute:

System.Data.Services.Common.HasStreamAttribute()